# Trouble to link to a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
include('base.php');
?>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['MomentEvent']))
{
     $MomentEvent = intval($_GET['MomentEvent']);
     $dn = mysql_query('select TitreEvent, DescriptionEvent from users_event where  MomentEvent="'.$MomentEvent.'"');
     if(mysql_num_rows($dn)>0)
     {
             $dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn);
             ?>
```

My problem is that the link to the users_event table is never made, and the:

> «Sorry TitreEvent not found»

message always pop-up in my face. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: THE FULL CODE**

```
<?php
include('base.php');
?>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['MomentEvent']))
 {
     $MomentEvent = intval($_GET['MomentEvent']);
     $dn = mysql_query('select TitreEvent, DescriptionEvent from users_event where MomentEvent="'.$MomentEvent.'"');
     if(mysql_num_rows($dn)>0)
     {
             $dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn);

 ?>
 This is the profile of "<?php echo htmlentities($dnn['TitreEvent']); ?>" :
 <table style="width:500px;">
     <tr>
     <td><?php
 if($dnn['avatar']!='')
{
     echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($dnn['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" alt="Avatar"      style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" />';
}
 else
{
     echo 'This user dont have an avatar.';
 }
?></td>
     <td class="left"><h1><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['TitreEvent'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?   ></h1>
      Email: <?php echo htmlentities($dnn['DescriptionEvent'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?><br />
      </tr>
 </table>
 <?php
     }
     else
     {
             echo 'Sorry TitreEvent not found';
     }
 }
 else
 {
     echo 'The user ID is not defined.';
 }
 ?>
                      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: seems like your missing a lot of your code here

Comment: paste here your error

Comment: First question is, are there any errors (if not, are you certain error-reporting is on)? Second, is `$_GET['MomentEvent']` set?

Comment: Yes, it's set on another page.

Comment: @freddy well, that sounds like your problem. To verify, is it set in the URL's query-string such as `http://domain/somepage.php?MomentEvent=15` or are you doing something like `$_GET['MomentEvent'] = 15;` on a different page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quotes mixed and matched way too much. Try this

```
$dn = mysql_query("select TitreEvent, DescriptionEvent from users_event where  MomentEvent=$MomentEvent ");
```

Comment: It looked like your issue was that you opened with single quotes but then closed that with double quotes.